# Setting up and Cleanning a DB after test Postgress and PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

I am creating tests for an API. I would like to set up the DB and clean it up for each test. The problem is that my DB is very complex and large, so I would like to know if there is a way to do a complete set up and clean up of the entire test DB which is not too heavy. Thanks for your recommendations. If you need more details let me know. In case this helps, I am using phpunit for the tests and using symphony as my framework.

Comment: What about making DB duplicate and after every test you can just overwrite DB you just used with original (other) one. You can clone it pretty fast, i.e. from phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Thanks @MilanG for your quick response. I thought about that too. The thing is the test will be use by other people too so I will need to set it up before the test also. I am looking for a way to upload the entire sql file using php and in a way that wont be too heavy on the system as the DB has many tables and lots of data. Well that las part is relative but lets say large for my system.

Comment: You can then have mysql database dump and then from php call console mysql command to import that dump into db. So any time you want to "reset" your table just execute "exec" or some similar command to call mysql to re-import db.

Comment: Thanks @MilanG. I made a test DB and 'reset' it by using the pg_restore calling it  with the exec. So thanks a lot. Now I created a console command to reset all test DB. Thanks

Comment: Voting up answers/comments is another way to say thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple with template databases.
You create and populate the test database you want, let's call it `test_template`.
Then make sure that nobody can connect:

```
ALTER DATABASE test_template ALLOW_CONNECTIONS false IS_TEMPLATE true;
```

Then create your test database with

```
CREATE DATABASE test123 TEMPLATE test_template;
```

For cleaning up, you just drop the database. You'll have to make sure that nobody is connected when you drop it, use the function `pg_terminate_backend` to kill any remaining connections.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, This was very helpful. I used this and after used the pg_restore for maintaining the test DB clean.